# 'Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]

Tags: endeca

While trying to access the `Experience manager`, I was getting following error.

`There was a problem with your request: faultCode:Server.Error.Request faultString:'HTTP request error' faultDetail:'Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]. URL: http://10.11.33.111:8000/ifcr/wb//landing/LandingPagesGroups.action'`

See the screenshot as well.

[image]

Comment: Did you get this on the JSP page or in the logs? The log files are located in [ENDECA_HOME]/ToolsAndFrameworks/[version]/server/workspace/logs. Check if there is any more information in any of the log files there, especially ifcr.log

Comment: This is happening every time when we restart the server.

Comment: Are you running workbench in `8000` port?  Typically it would be `8006`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `error 2032` on `endeca` workbench happens if you open workbenches in two browser windows at the same time, and logout from one window and then try to login again while the workbench is open in another window. Close Workbench in other browsers and then logout and login.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to open Endeca experience manager in multiple tabs. Delete cookies and try.

However, you can use different browser to open experience manager using same id and password